# create random number in a specific area of a square

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to create such a symmetric matrix with a different density of elements in each area.

[image]

matrix is `256x256`, in **level 1** I have 16 square with length 16 each has 10 element:

```
#LEVEL I
C = np.zeros((256,256))
s = 0
for k in range(16):
    if k > 0:
        s += 16
    while m < 10: #number of elements in most inner square
        i,j = np.random.randint(s,s+16,size=2) # randint(low,high,size)
        C[i,j] = C[j,i] = 1
        m = 0.5 * np.sum(C[s:s+16,s:s+16])  # count the number of elements
```

in **level 2** I have 4 square with length 64, each have 4 elements except elements inside the small squares ( 4 square each 10 elements + 4 elements in larger square).

For level 2 I need to create integer random numbers that have no overlapping with small squares.

```
#LEVEL II
s = 0
for k in range(4):
    if k>0:
        s += 64
    while m < (40+4):
        # create i,j with no overlapping with small squares
        C[i,j]=C[j,i] = 1
        m = 0.5 * np.sum(C[s:s+64,s:s+64])
```

I appreciate any idea or comment.

**#Edit**
I think one solution could be define another square matrix with subsquares  all aij=1 and compare the number of elements in each while loop.

Comment: Your requirements are not quite clear. Do you mean at level 1 you have 256 squares of size 16x16 inside your matrix of size 256x256? What does it mean that each level 1 square "has 10 element"? And so on.

Comment: I think the figure in more clear than my explanation. you can see 1 large square. inside it 4 smaller ones (light red- level 2) and 16 smaller square (dark red- level 1).  `1(256x256) = 4(4x64) = 16 (16x16)`

Comment: Each `(aij = aji) !=0` is one element in symmetric matrix

Comment: @Abolfazl Numbers between each of the square on certain Level can overlap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

# Matrix size and inner squares length
s = 256
L2 = 64
L1 = 16

# Create matrix and masks along MAIN diagonal
C = 1 - np.random.random((s, s))
L2_mask = np.array([range(s)]*s)//L2 + np.array([range(s-1, -1, -1)]*s).T//L2
L1_mask = np.array([range(s)]*s)//L1 + np.array([range(s-1, -1, -1)]*s).T//L1

# Fill in inner squares
C[np.where(L2_mask == 3)] = np.random.randint(2, 10, 16384)
C[np.where(L1_mask == 15)] = np.random.randint(100, 200, 4096)
```

To generate a symmetric matrix I can suggest two methods:

```
# Turn matrix into symmetric
C_symm = (C + C.T)//2
```

or

```
# Turn matrix into symmetric
C_symm = np.tril(C) + np.tril(C, -1).T
```

And now just flip it:

```
# Flip it
C_final = np.fliplr(C_symm)
```